# Traduction du néologisme anglais "Malaphor"

Tags: traduction, figure-de-style

J'ai récemment découvert le concept de "malaphor", illustré par de nombreux exemples anglophones [ici](https://malaphors.com/) et défini ainsi sur [en.Wiktionary.org](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/malaphor) :

> (rare neologism) An idiom blend: an error in which two similar figures of speech are merged, producing a nonsensical result.
>
> Examples include "We'll burn that bridge when we come to it" (from "We'll cross that bridge when we come to it" and "burn one's bridges") and "stir the apple cart" (from "upset the apple cart" and "stir the pot").

Outre la traduction littérale par un autre néologisme "malaphore", y aurait-il un mot plus conventionnel pour désigner une telle tournure ?

Comment: Les Québécois parlent de [« perronismes »](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perronisme), combinaisons de métaphores et / ou expressions existantes. « Atteindre la lumière au fond du baril », combinaison de « Voir la lumière au bout du tunnel » et « Atteindre le fond du baril ». Mais je ne connais pas de mot équivalent en France.

Comment: *`Il ne faut pas prendre les sampans du pont Thieu pour des cannots de sauvetage!`*  - Gotlieb -

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Quand chacun voit midi a quatorze heure, il faut savoir remettre les pendules à leur place". J'ai longtemps entendu le terme d'expressions ou  **métaphores douteuses**. Sur ce site d'exemples ("Elle était accumulée au pied du mur"), on trouve des [déformades](http://www.algerie-dz.com/forums/showthread.php?t=45924).

Answer (score 6):

On peut parler en français de « mélange de métaphores », de même qu'en anglais on parle de « *mixed metaphor* ». Le français dispose également d'une pléthore de termes savants pour désigner des figures de style, qui ne sont pas forcément connus du grand public. Un mélange de métaphores est une forme de [syllepse](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syllepse) sur le sens. On peut également voir le premier exemple comme un [zeugme sémantique](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeugma_(stylistique)#Zeugme_s.C3.A9mantique) (le mot *bridge* est pris dans deux contextes différents) voire une [antanaclase](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antanaclase).

Answer (score 4):

En cherchant *[pataquès](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/pataqu%C3%A8s)*, j'ai trouvé :

> ***Patafouillis***, subst. masc.,rare, fam., synon. (supra A 2).
>
> Il leur expliquait [à l'office] avec force gestes, dans un *patafouillis* de français et d'italien (...) que la donna était très gentille (L. Daudet, Bacchantes, 1931, p.74).

Le correcteur orthographique grimace, mais il s'agit bien ici de mélanger deux sources pour un résultat confus.

Ce mot aussi rare et aussi peu connu que ceux de la liste des syllepses, est cependant compréhensible par tout un chacun, étant lui-même, à l'oreille, une sorte de ***[macédoine](http://www.cnrtl.fr/lexicographie/mac%C3%A9doine)*** de patates !
... on quitte les conventions académiques pour les conventions culinaires plus connues du commun des mortels :

> Laissons les néologismes académiques venus des anciens Grecs, amusons-nous de ce *patafouillis* de mots, de cette *macédoine* d'idées saugrenues !

Answer (score 4):

Je vais peut être mettre un coup de pied dans le plat, mais je dirais un **cafouillage métaphorique** (*metaphorical screw-up*), car je penses que c'est ce qui a le plus de chance d'être compris.

Comme dit @Gilles, à moins d'avoir fait l'effort d'apprendre par cœur une liste de figures de rhétorique la très grande majorité des gens ne comprendrait pas le terme existant (si il existe).

Answer (score 0):

Je pense que le concept est de relier 2 expression ayant un sens commun dont le sens ne fait aucun doute(1) puis aussi la possibilité d'en relier 2 dont les termes ont une connotation distincte et dont on doit deviner le (nouveau) sens(2):
1.Brasser la girafe ou peigner de l'air...lol
2.Pigeon de panurge, avoir un biscuit dans le tiroir...

Comment: Mais pour répondre à la question, comment traduire « malaphor »  ?  Bienvenue sur French SE.  Il est utile de lire le [help] et le [FAQ] pour améliorer la réponse.

Answer (score 0):

Je pense qu’un des meilleurs exemples en français serait : «  ça rentre comme papa dans du beurre » ou «  comme du beurre dans maman » ( comme papa dans maman / comme dans du beurre )

Comment: Ceci n'est pas une réponse... les exemples sont nombreux, lequel est le "meilleur" dépend de la personne, j'aime beaucoup "Il n'a pas inventé le fil à couper l'eau tiède" personnellement, mais la question est de savoir comment ce phénomène s'appelle en Français le cas échéant...